# Are Java function parameters always passed-by-value?

Tags: java, parameters

Just a quick question about how parameters are passed in Java...

```
...
            if ((index = stdout.indexOf(pattern)) != -1) {
                tidy(stdout, index + pattern.length());
                return true;
            } else if ((index = stderr.indexOf(pattern)) != -1) {
                tidy(stderr, index + pattern.length());
                return true;
...

    private void tidy(StringBuffer buffer, int i) {
        logger.info("Truncating buffer: " + buffer);
        buffer = new StringBuffer(buffer.substring(i));
        logger.info("Buffer now: " + buffer);
    }
```

In this case, will stdout and stderr (used as parameters in tidy()) have their values changed to new StringBuffer(buffer.substring(i))? My assumption is that they will as object variables(object pointers) are always passed-by-value?

Comment: see this for an in-depth explanation with examples http://javadude.com/articles/passbyvalue.htm

Comment: see also this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You misstate what is going on here -- the object references are passed by value (a copy of the reference is made), so stdout and stderr do *not* get modified when you call tidy.  The *copies* that are made of them get modified when you execute line 2 of `tidy`.

Parameter passing in Java is a source of confusion for a lot of people.  Here's [a good explanation](http://javadude.com/articles/passbyvalue.htm).

Comment: thanks! i like your reference to this 'pass-by-value' problem

Comment: i would not call that a good explanation... i don't understand it.

Answer (score 2):

Java parameters are always pass-by-value, period.

Here's a cute article explaining the phenomenon:
http://www.javaranch.com/campfire/StoryPassBy.jsp

In your case, it doesn't matter if it's pbr or pbv, because you are re-assigning sb to a new object (by calling `buffer = new StringBuffer(...)` and `buffer.subString(...)` does not mutate the object itself).

Answer (score 2):

From James Gosling in "The Java Programming Language":

> "...There is exactly one parameter passing mode in Java - pass by value - and that keeps things simple. .."

I think that's the final authority on this.

Answer (score 1):

No, stdout and stderr will not be changed, and yes, parameters are passed by value.

The variable "buffer" will be set equal to stdout, meaning buffer will point to the same object at first. When buffer is changed to point to a new object, the old stdout reference will still point to the old object.

Answer (score 0):

Your assumption is incorrect. Why?

Because **function parameters are always passed-by-value**.

When you do:

```
buffer = new StringBuffer(buffer.substring(i));
```

you are assigning a new `StringBuffer` to a local reference that was copied from the parameter reference. So, the *original* buffer doesn't change.