# Are String Arrays mutable?

Tags: java, arrays, string, types, mutable

I wonder if String arrays in Java are mutable ? I know that Strings are immutable, but how about string Arrays ?

If I have a string array, and change the content, will a new string object be created ? Or will the actual value just be changed ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Arrays in Java are mutable, it not depends on array type, they will be mutable in any case.

Answer (score 19):

The `String`s contained in the `String[]` are indeed immutable, but the array is mutable.

This is well explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2535564/1065197):

> - Immutability means that objects of a certain type can not change in any meaningful way to outside observers
>
>   - `Integer`, `String`, etc are immutable
>   - Generally all value types should be
> - Array objects are mutable
>
>   - It may be an array of references to immutable types, but the array itself is mutable
>
>     - Meaning you can set those references to anything you want
>     - Also true for array of primitives
>   - An immutable array will not be practical
> - References to objects can be shared
>
>   - If the object is mutable, mutation will be seen through all these references

EDIT:

Somewhat related: [Why can't strings be mutable in Java and .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/93091/1065197)

Answer (score 5):

As far as i remember the field in your array will reference another String

```
String[] array {"I","like","rain"};
array[2] = "sun"
```

your array can be changed. the Strings themselves not.

Answer (score 2):

The `String[]` array does not contain references to string variables, as some people might say. The `String[]` array contains values (or more exactly references to values), but not references to variables.

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String one="1";
        String two="2";

        String[] arr = {one, two};

        System.out.println(arr[1]);
        // Result is "2"

        two="3";

        System.out.println(arr[1]);
        // Result is still "2"
    }
}
```

So, as you can see, the `arr[1]` is not a reference to `String two`. It got the value from the variable `two` and that's it. Changing the variable `two` did not affect `arr[1]`.

The same thing about `ArrayList`:

```java
//...

    String one="1";
        String two="2";
    List arr2 = new ArrayList<String>();
        
        arr2.add(one);
        arr2.add(two);
        
        System.out.println(arr2.get(0));
   // Result is "1"

        one = "one";
        System.out.println(arr2.get(0));
   // Result is still "1", not "one"

//...
```

Therefore the array `String` elements are immutable (which is logical, because `String`s are immutable).

The mutability occurs when you pass the arrays `arr` or `arr2` themselves to a procedure, not their immutable `String` elements.

For example:

```java
   change(arr);
   // where arr is a String[] array of {"1","2"}
   // see the procedure below

     System.out.println(arr[0]);
  // Result is "one"
  
        
  // ...
    
    static void change(String[] someArray){
        someArray[0]="one";
    }
```

In other words, the array is passed by reference (=mutable), but its string elements are passed by value (immutable).

Answer (score 1):

In Arrays, each element is just a pointer to an object. So, when you do something like

```
String one = "1";
String two = "2";
String three = "3";
String four = "4";
String[] myStringArray = {one, two, three};
myStringArray[2] = four;
```

Then the pointer that was at the 3rd element of the array now points to the **four** instead of **three**.