# AP Comp Sci print method

Tags: java, pointers

```
public void changeParams(int k, int[] A, String s){
    k++;
    A[0]++;
    s += "X";
}
public void print(){
    int k = 0;
    int[] A = {10, 20};
    String s = "aaa";
    changeParams(k, A, s);
    System.out.println(k + " " + A[0] + " " + s);
}
```

The question is asking "What is output when method print is called?" I think the answer is 0 10 aaa but the answer key says 0 11 aaa Could someone explain why? Thanks

Comment: surely there's a definitive  way to tell, eh?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it doesn't pose a suitable problem to be solved.

Comment: I've read a Java book but I was just confused on the concept of what was immutable or not with this code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is `0 11 aaa`.

The `A[0]++` in `changeParams()` affects the value stored in the array because a pointer is passed into the method and so operations affect the shared data. Debug this and step through it...

```
public class SO {

    public void changeParams(int k, int[] A, String s){
        k++;
        A[0]++;
        s += "X";
    }
    public void print(){
        int k = 0;
        int[] A = {10, 20};
        String s = "aaa";
        changeParams(k, A, s);
        System.out.println(k + " " + A[0] + " " + s);
    }

    public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
        new SO().print();
    }
}
```

Comment: oh so it only effects arrays and not the int and the String?

Comment: Could you at least vote up for my answer and mark it correct?

Answer (score 2):

The answer is `0 11 aaa`.  The *reason* for it is that Java is pass by value.

Here's what that means.

In your `changeParams` method, you're affecting all three arguments to it - the int passed in, the array, and the `String`.

When you're passing something by value, you're [giving them a copy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/430958/1079354) (of sorts) of the value.  What this means is, in general, you can't destroy or tamper with the original value passed in - with respect to primitives and immutable classes.  `String` is immutable, so any operation done to it will produce a new `String` - and the operation done on it will only live inside of that method.

Arrays [are not immutable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2535564/1079354).  If you pass in an array, you have the ability to index into it and change any value you like, which may or may not be desirable to your program's intentions.

The same is also true if you pass in a mutable object - `Calendar`, for example; if you pass in a `Calendar` instance, you will be able to modify its state (day of week, hour, second, millisecond, etc), and potentially cause havoc when you're trying to use the same instance for something else later.

**This** is why the only thing that changes is `11`.  The value at `A[0]` has been incremented, and because arrays aren't immutable, you are effectively changing the value for the array at a given location.