# reason: why java is not pass by reference?

Tags: java, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

Java is strictly pass by value..I am still confused with this concept.
I have gone through many websites to get an answer for this but I am not able to find any good reason.
Is there any proper reason why Java is not pass by reference?

Comment: On what level are you expecting an answer ? Is that a theoretical question ? Do you want to know the reasoning behind this design ?

Comment: This question has been asked before:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5298421/why-doesnt-java-support-pass-by-reference-like-c

Comment: Pointers and dereferencing where by far the least intuitive part of C++, java's pass a reference by value solves almost all the usage cases for C++'s pass by reference while avoid all the confusion.

Answer (score 2):

The value of a `reference variable` is an "address" in Java. When you pass a reference variable to a method, a new reference variable is placed on the stack and a copy of the passed reference variable's value is used to initialize the new local reference varaible's value, just like any primitive type.

That is the classic definition of `pass by value`.

**NOTE**: While you can think of the reference as a memory address, it's not. The underlying mechanism makes it act logically as if it were though.

**SHORT VERSION**: references are simple variables just like the other primitive types for purposes of passing arguments to methods. What you can do with them once passed is obviously different.