# Java - Static Void Method - LinkedList - Pass By Value

Tags: java, linked-list, pass-by-value

Is it possible to create the following static void method in Java?

```
public static void reverse(LinkedList<String> linkedlist)

{

//Code would go here...

}
```

As I understand it, since Java is pass-by-value this isn't possible, correct?

Comment: Have you tried to code this to see what happens before posting here? A LinkedList is a *reference* variable and therein lies all the difference. My suggestion: try it first. This site makes a poor substitute for your very own Java compiler.

Comment: Hint: There's a static method `Collections.reverse(List<?> list)` that works for any kind of modifiable list, including `LinkedList`.

Comment: When dealing with **objects** Java passes by value **their references**. It even creates an impression that Java passes objects by reference.

Comment: I think the best way to verify the question is: ---------- Have a try in you IDE like eclipse. If it doesn't throw exception ,Codes are right. Otherwise something wrong. ----------

Comment: "doesn't throw exception" is not exactly a complete test that the code is correct.

Comment: @PM77-1: Well, you don't really "deal with objects" in Java. You deal with references.

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about the stock `java.util.LinkedList` class, then it's certainly possible to write such a method. In fact, there already is one: `java.util.Collections.reverse(List<?> list)` that works with any modifiable list (including `LinkedList`). It reverses the elements of the list.

If you're talking about a custom `LinkedList` class, it depends on how the class is implemented. If a `LinkedList` object is just a linked series of nodes with data, then no, you cannot reverse the list because you cannot change the first element; it would require changing what `linkedList` references. You can do that internally in the method, but it won't affect the actual parameter in the calling code. That's the consequence of pass-by-value.

However, `java.util.LinkedList` is not structured like that. The nodes are internal to the `LinkedList` object itself. The object reference does not need to change to change the order of all the elements.

Answer (score 1):

Java supports only pass by value but the code you posted will not make any error because it is also pass by value.
refer these links [Is Java "pass-by-reference" or "pass-by-value"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference), [Are Java function parameters always passed-by-value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1110826/are-java-function-parameters-always-passed-by-value), [Immutable and pass by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8257404/immutable-and-pass-by-value), http://www.javaworld.com/javaqa/2000-05/03-qa-0526-pass.html